# Действия с элементами сразу после рендеринга

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Друзья, мне нужно взять контекст канваса сразу после того, как реакт отрендерил класс и проделать с ним манипуляции. Как это сделать? Проблема в том, что refs не доступны ни в getInitialState, ни перед ретурном в render(), ни внутри самого ретурна, когда в фигурных вызываешь метод элемента. А при вызове этих же методов по событию, refs доступны. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл ответ в документации. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html
все refs доступны в componentDidMount()